# npm run dev Missing argument values

Tags: node.js

npm run dev error
Missing argument values: config-name, context, entry, module-bind, module-bind-post, module-bind-pre, output-path, output-filename, output-chunk-filename, output-source-map-filename, output-public-path, output-jsonp-function, output-library, output-library-target, records-input-path, records-output-path, records-path, define, target, watch-aggregate-timeout, devtool, resolve-alias, resolve-extensions, resolve-loader-alias, optimize-max-chunks, optimize-min-chunk-size, prefetch, provide, plugin, open-page

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! CCRMS@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the CCRMS@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/wangweiyi/.npm/_logs/2018-01-09T01_55_19_207Z-debug.log

Comment: This is your error output. What is exactly your question? Have you looked at the log file mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're encountering the following "trending" issue:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1229

Try downgrading `webpack-dev-server` to v2.9.7 as suggested to resolve the issue.

(Note: the log file won't show much, and the upvoted comment above isn't helpful at all. Unfortunately this seems to be the prevailing climate on SO these days, and why the site will devolve into complete uselessness shortly. Perhaps we can bring back Experts Exchange.)

Answer (score 0):

The same to SexxLuthor's answer ,use this command:
npm install webpack-dev-server@2.9.7 --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

This is webpack-dev-server@2.10.0 bug.
See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1259